# How to trigger an image change on a Tkinter window upon receiving data from a Publisher?

Tags: python, tkinter, mosquitto, paho

**Base Idea**

I am using the `MQTT` protocol (Broker: Mosquitto and Client implementation via Eclipse Paho) to get periodic data. I want to show an image upon getting a particular number x in the data and change the image if I get another number y.

In layman terms, I am getting some data in JSON format in an interval of 10 seconds, and want to display or change an image with respect to the data received.

**Code**

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import datetime
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()


def drawImage(payload):
    pic = payload['camera']
    canvas.delete("all")
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(str(pic) + ".png"))
    canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=img)
    root.mainloop()


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe("home/camera")


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    t = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    payload = json.loads(msg.payload)
    print("Data received at: {0} || Topic: {1} || Message: {2}".format(t, msg.topic, str(msg.payload)))
    drawImage(payload)


client = mqtt.Client(client_id="cameratester")
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
```

**Brief explaining of how the code works:**

Whenever new data is received `on_message` gets called which in-turn calls the `drawImage` function that draws the image.

**Problem**

Image draws upon receiving the first message, but code seems to hang there. My client doesn't accept any of the other incoming messages. Upon closing the image window, the `print("Data received at: {0} || Topic: {1} || Message: {2}".format(t, msg.topic, str(msg.payload)))` line of code starts executing again, but no image gets displayed.

**Some Research**

After going through the plathora of `How to change image in Tkinter` questions on StackOverflow, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691102/changing-image-in-tkinter-canvas-in-while-loop) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482081/how-to-update-the-image-of-a-tkinter-label-widget), it became evident that `root.mainloop()` is a blocking call and the flow wouldn't execute further until the window is closed. It was mentioned that if I want to change the image, I would need to assigned a callback to an event, like clicking a button and do `panel.configure(image=img2)` to change the image.

But since my design doesn't have any buttons, I cannot follow the button-callback methodology.

So, how can I trigger a change the image on Tkinter window upon receiving data from a Publisher (MQTT)?

Should I not use Tkinter, some other package is better suited for this requirement? Or am I missing something really basic.

Please advice.

Comment: tkinker works bad with external event loop. You have internal one for tkinter even loop and making mqtt.Client event loop, which one should proceed? drawImage starts tkinter's so it is.